# Can't figure out the error to this code

Tags: programming

I've written up this very simply code to control transistors in an inverter circuit. The editor is flagging up errors which I can't see myself. I'm pretty new to Arduino programming but it's very simple code and can't see why it's being shown as having errors.

At first glance, what am I missing? I've pasted a section below:

```
int Phase1pos = 13;
int Phase2pos = 12;
int Phase3pos = 11;
int Phase1neg = 10;
int Phase2neg = 9;
int Phase3neg = 8;

void setup() {
pinMode(Phase1pos, OUTPUT);
pinMode(Phase2pos, OUTPUT);
pinMode(Phase3pos, OUTPUT);
pinMode(Phase1neg, OUTPUT);
pinMode(Phase2neg, OUTPUT);
pinMode(Phase3neg, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    delayMicroseconds(16);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(16);

    delayMicroseconds(7);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(108);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(7);

    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(159);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);

    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(104);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(208);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(104);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, LOW);

    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(159);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, LOW);

    delayMicroseconds(7);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(108);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(7);

    delayMicroseconds(16);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, LOW);
    digitalWrite(16);

    delayMicroseconds(28);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(180);
    delayMicroseconds(180);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(28);

    delayMicroseconds(16);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(16);

    delayMicroseconds(7);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(108);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);

    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(159);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);

    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(104);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(208);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(104);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);

    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(159);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);

    delayMicroseconds(7);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(108);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(7);

    delayMicroseconds(16);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(16);

    delayMicroseconds(28);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(180);
    delayMicroseconds(180);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(28);

    delayMicroseconds(16);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(16);

    delayMicroseconds(7);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(108);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(7);

    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(159);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);

    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(104);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(208);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(104);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);

    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(159);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);

    delayMicroseconds(7);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(108);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(7);

    delayMicroseconds(16);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase1pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(16);

    delayMicroseconds(28);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(180);
    delayMicroseconds(180);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(28);

    delayMicroseconds(16);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(16);

    delayMicroseconds(7);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(108);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(7);

    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(159);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);

    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(104);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(208);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(104);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);

    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(159);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);

    delayMicroseconds(7);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(108);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(7);

    delayMicroseconds(16);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(16);

    delayMicroseconds(28);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(180);
    delayMicroseconds(180);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(28);

    delayMicroseconds(16);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(16);

    delayMicroseconds(7);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(108);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(7);

    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(159);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);

    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(104);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(208);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(104);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, LOW);

    delayMicroseconds(2);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(159);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(47);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(80);
    digitalWrite(Phase2neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(2);

    delayMicroseconds(7);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(108);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(93);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(7);

    delayMicroseconds(16);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase3pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(16);

    delayMicroseconds(28);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(180);
    delayMicroseconds(180);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, LOW);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(28);

    delayMicroseconds(16);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(54);
    digitalWrite(Phase3neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(138);
    digitalWrite(Phase1neg, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(27);
    digitalWrite(Phase2pos, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(16);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE. It would be helpful if you could post the error messages that you're getting.

Comment: Hi, thanks!  In function 'void loop()':
99: error: too few arguments to function 'void digitalWrite(uint8_t, uint8_t)'
109: error: at this point in file

Comment: I've found the one at line 109 but the one at 99 I can't seem to see

Comment: I copy/pasted it, fixed 109, it compiled...

Answer (score 5):

Here's line 109:

```
 digitalWrite(16);
```

As the error message says, there aren't enough arguments. It looks like you meant to call `delayMicroseconds()` there instead of `digitalWrite()`.